# IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: android, filter, android-arrayadapter

I'm using a custom ArrayAdapter to set the adapter on an AutocompleteTextView (AddressAdapter extends ArrayAdapter).

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
private ArrayList<String> mData;
ArrayList<String> listTempPrefix = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
String valueText;
String[] words;
String ulcase;

public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> bS) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    mData = bS;//new ArrayList<String>();
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    synchronized (listTempPrefix)
    {
        return listTempPrefix.size();
    }
}

@Override
public String getItem(int index)  
{
    synchronized (listTempPrefix)
    {
        try {
            //Log.e("Error", listTempPrefix.get(index));
            return listTempPrefix.get(index);
        } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.e("Error", "IndexOutOfBoundsException");
            return "";
        }
    }

}

@Override
public Filter getFilter()
{
    Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
        {

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            synchronized (filterResults)
            {
                listTempPrefix.clear();
                listTemp.clear();
                //Log.e("1", "1");

                try {
                if(constraint != null) {
                    // A class that queries a web API, parses the data and returns an ArrayList<Style>
                    //StyleFetcher fetcher = new StyleFetcher();
                    //try {
                        //mData = fetcher.retrieveResults(constraint.toString());
                    //}
                    //catch(Exception e) {}
                    // Now assign the values and count to the FilterResults object


                    for(String value: mData) {
                        valueText = value.toLowerCase();

                        //System.out.println("constraintH - " + constraint);

                        constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                        ulcase = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                        //System.out.println("ulcase - " + ulcase);

                        if (valueText.startsWith(ulcase)) {
                            listTempPrefix.add(value);
                        } else {
                            words = valueText.split(" ");
                            //final int wordCount = words.length;

                            // Start at index 0, in case valueText starts with space(s)
                            for (int k = 0; k < words.length; k++) {
                                if (words[k].startsWith(ulcase)) {
                                    listTemp.add(value);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        ///listTemp.add(mData.get(i));
                        //filterResults.count = mData.size();
           //           System.out.println("mData" + i + mData.get(i));
                    }
                    //Log.e("2", "2");
           //       System.out.println("size " + listTemp.size() + " value" + listTemp);

                    listTempPrefix.addAll(listTemp);

                    filterResults.values = listTempPrefix;

                    filterResults.count = listTempPrefix.size();
                    //System.out.println("size " + filterResults.count + " value" + filterResults.values);

                    //System.out.println("constraint" + constraint);

                }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                return filterResults;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults filterResults) 
        {
            synchronized (filterResults)
            {
                if(filterResults != null && filterResults.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                //Log.e("notifyDataSetChanged", "notifyDataSetChanged");
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    //Log.e("notifyDataSetInvalidated", "notifyDataSetInvalidated");
                }
            }
        }
    };
    return myFilter;
}
```

}

What I got sometimes: please notice, it happens really rarely. But I'd like to get rid of this bug completely. Here is partial stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(-1, class android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownListView) with Adapter(class com.example.test.AutoCompleteAdapter)].
```

The problem maybe that the fast input from keybord, method notifyDataSetChanged () issn't call. But i'am not sure.

Answer (score 12):

Change publishResults to

```
@Override 
protected void publishResults(final CharSequence contraint, final FilterResults filterResults) { 
    listTempPrefix = (List) results.values;
    if(filterResults != null && filterResults.count > 0) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
}
```

This way the GUI thread updates the results instead of performFiltering which runs in a background thread.

Remove listTempPrefix references from performFiltering and use a local variable there to store the results and return them through FilterResults

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks! Solved the IllegalStateException problem with the demo code that Google has provided for Places Autocompletion at https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android

Comment: @nhpatt The answer did work, just for completeness the parameter for publishResults is set to filterResults (instead of results when used 'results.values')

Answer (score 8):

You're changing the `listTempPrefix` array on `performFiltering` (using clear and addAll), so you would need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` to avoid this exception.

But `performFiltering` is not called on the ui thread, so calling `notifyDataSetChanged` would also raise an exception.

The best way to solve this problem is changing the listTempPrefix array inside `publishResults`, and then call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Remove the changes made to `listTempPrefix` from the `performFiltering` method (you might need to create a temp array depending on your filter logic).

On `publishResults`, update your `listTempPrefix` array with the values contained on `filterResults`, and call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Here is an exemple based on your code:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter()
{
    Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
        {

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            synchronized (filterResults)
            {
                //listTempPrefix.clear(); // Don't change listTempPrefix here
                 ...
                        ulcase = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                        //System.out.println("ulcase - " + ulcase);

                        if (valueText.startsWith(ulcase)) {
                            //listTempPrefix.add(value); // Don't change listTempPrefix
                            // To keep your logic you might need an aux array 
                            // for this part
                        } else {
                            ...
                        }

                    //listTempPrefix.addAll(listTemp); // Don't change it

                    filterResults.values = listTempPrefix; // No problem here

                    filterResults.count = listTempPrefix.size(); // No problem here
                    //System.out.println("size " + filterResults.count + " value" + filterResults.values);

                    //System.out.println("constraint" + constraint);

                }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                return filterResults;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults filterResults) 
        {
            // At this point, make the changes you need to listTempPrefix
            // using filterResults.values
            synchronized (filterResults)
            {
                if(filterResults != null && filterResults.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                //Log.e("notifyDataSetChanged", "notifyDataSetChanged");
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    //Log.e("notifyDataSetInvalidated", "notifyDataSetInvalidated");
                }
            }
        }
    };
    return myFilter;
}
```

Comment: I do not know much English. I did not fully understand your point, you can write a sample.

Comment: This worked for me.  This should be the accepted answer.  I wish I could upvote more for you @Marcelo.  Saved my day!!!

Comment: IMHO filterResults != null not needed because its always true

Answer (score 0):

You must call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method as soon as the dataset (`ArrayList`, `Array`, `Cursor`, etc.,) backing your `Adapter` changes. Or else you will end up with this `Exception`.

Comment: Could you write a sample how to get the IllegalStateException?