# Android java.lang.IllegalStateException on ListView

Tags: java, android

I use `ListActivity` with `SpecialAdapter` that show some log information.
I do not use background thread but I get an error when scroll list:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(16908298, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class ru.FoxGSM.ui.DebugActivity$SpecialAdapter)]
```

Please, help me.

(`FoxLog` is static class that get log information, perhaps from another thread. But in list a want show `FoxLog` snapshot)

```
public class DebugActivity extends ListActivity {

private class SpecialAdapter extends BaseAdapter    {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public SpecialAdapter(Context context)  { 
        super();
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount()   {
        return  FoxLog.count();
    }

    public long getItemId(int index)    {
        return index;
    }

    public Object getItem(int index)    {
        return  FoxLog.get(FoxLog.count()-index-1);
    }

    // Get the type of View
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)   {
        TextView text;

        if (convertView == null)    {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.debug_list, null);
            text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            convertView.setTag(text);
        }   else
            text = (TextView) convertView.getTag();

        String s = (String) getItem(position);
        if (s==null)
            return convertView; 

        text.setText(s);

        boolean isError = false;
        if (s!=null && s.length()>0)    {
            String prefix = s.substring(0, 1);
            if (prefix.equals("E") || prefix.equals("W"))
                isError = true;
        }
        if (isError)
            text.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
        else
            text.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        return convertView;    

    }
}

private void RefreshData()  {
    FoxLog.ReInit(this);        
    SpecialAdapter adapter = (SpecialAdapter)this.getListAdapter();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {           
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.debug);

    FoxLog.ReInit(this);        
    SpecialAdapter adapter = new SpecialAdapter(this);                
    setListAdapter(adapter);        

    Button mExit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exit);
    mExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }          
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: The question is answered here

[IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156299/illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed-but-listview-did-n

Comment: where are you calling `RefreshData`? try to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` on UI thread (fx.: in `activity.runonuithread`)

Comment: Error is not happening when I click button "Refresh". Error happened when I scroll list :((

Comment: if error is happening when you try to scroll list that means its in your getview method or getItem method.try checking both of this method by putting logs and try some debugging.