# Autocompletetextview:java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: android, android-adapter, autocompletetextview, illegalstateexception

I am getting below exception sometimes when i click on an item in autocompletetextview.I am NOT running this in background thread and i am using notifyDataSetChanged() also.I failed to understand where am I going wrong.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes.
```

Code

```
 searchautocomplete.setAdapter(searchAutoCompleteAdapter= new SearchAutoCompleteAdapter(getApplicationContext(),searchautocomplete.getText().toString(),this)); // 'this' is Activity instance
      searchautocomplete.setLoadingIndicator(
               (android.widget.ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_loading_indicator));
 searchautocomplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                UserVideo data=(UserVideo)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                searchautocomplete.setText("");
                if ((data.getIsVideo()))
                {

                    searchAutoCompleteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    setSearchVideoToShow(data);
                    mSearchLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    switchFragment(HomeActivity.FRAGMENT_VIDEO_SEARCH, false, "Video Details");
                }
                else if ((!data.getIsVideo()))
                {
                    searchAutoCompleteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //mSingleClickHandle.put(ENABLE_FRAGMENT_SEARCH_VIEW, false);
                    setUserIdToShow(data.getUserId2());
                    closeDrawer();
                    mSearchLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    switchFragment(HomeActivity.FRAGMENT_PROFILE_VIEW, false, "video");
                }
            }
        });
```

Adapter

```
public class SearchAutoCompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private static final int MAX_RESULTS = 10;
    private Context mContext;

    private String searchString;
    List<UserObject> mUserList;
    List<UserObject> userList;
HomeActivity mHomeActivity;
    String url;
    private ArrayList<UserVideo> searchResponses=new ArrayList<UserVideo>();
    private ArrayList<UserVideo> searchUserResponses=new ArrayList<UserVideo>();

    public SearchAutoCompleteAdapter(Context c,String text,HomeActivity homeActivity) {
        mContext=c;
        searchString=text;
        mHomeActivity=homeActivity;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return searchResponses.size();
    }

    @Override
    public UserVideo getItem(int index) {
        return searchResponses.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_search_view, parent, false);

        }
        NetworkImageView userImageView = (NetworkImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_user_image);
        ImageView searchUser= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_user);
        ImageView searchVideo= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_video);
        TextView userNameView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_user_handle);

        TextView nameTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        if(getItem(position).getIsVideo())
        {
            searchVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            searchUser.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            nameTextView.setText(searchResponses.get(position).getCaption());
            userNameView.setText(searchResponses.get(position).getLocation());

            url=TremoURLs.VIDEO_THUMBNAIL_URL.replace("<fixme>", getItem(position).getId());
            LoadImage.loadImage(url, userImageView, R.drawable.default_video_img);
        }
        else
        {
           url= TremoURLs.USER_PROFILE_IMAGE_URL + getItem(position).getUserId2();
            searchUser.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            searchVideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
Log.e("bhuvnesh ","pos "+position);
            nameTextView.setText(searchResponses.get(position).getUserName());
            userNameView.setText(searchResponses.get(position).getUserHandle());

            LoadImage.loadImage(url, userImageView, R.drawable.default_video_img);

        }
      return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint.length() > 2)
                {
                    ArrayList<UserVideo> users = findResult(mContext, constraint.toString());
                    filterResults.values = users;
                    filterResults.count = users.size();
                }
                //notifyDataSetChanged();
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
            {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0)
                {
                    searchResponses = (ArrayList<UserVideo>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else
                {

                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }


    private ArrayList<UserVideo> findResult(final Context context, final String user)
    {


        SearchAPI.getSearchFeed(context,user,"", 10, mHomeActivity.mSettingsManager.getAccessToken(), new APIResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Object response) {

                searchResponses=(ArrayList<UserVideo>) response;
              for(UserVideo userVideo:searchResponses)
              {
                  userVideo.setIsVideo(true);
              }

                SearchAPI.getSearchUser(context,user,mHomeActivity.mSettingsManager.getAccessToken(), new APIResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Object response)
                    {
                        searchUserResponses=(ArrayList<UserVideo>) response;
                        for(UserVideo userVideo:searchUserResponses)
                        {
                            userVideo.setIsVideo(false);
                        }
                        searchResponses.addAll(searchUserResponses);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        return searchResponses;

    }
}
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156299/illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed-but-listview-did-n/20056706#20056706

Comment: Also try `yourListView.requestLayout()` after setting your adaper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding  `notifyDataSetChanged()`; inside  onResponse() of my inner API call resolved my issue..